# Pass multiple system parameters thorugh docker-compose-->dockerfile--> springboot application housed in docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, dockerfile

---

Below is the content of my docker-compose.yml file:

```
eureka-server:
  image: controlsplm/eureka-server
  environment:
      HOST_IP: X.X.X.X
      ACTIVE_PROFILE=docker-development-cloud
  ports:
   - "8761:8761"
  restart: always
```

And below is the content of my docker file:

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD eureka-server-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8761
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Denvironment=$HOST_IP","-Dspring.profiles.active=$ACTIVE_PROFILE","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

But when i run the docker container using compose, HOST_IP is picked up but not ACTIVE_PROFILE. AM i missing anything here? Kindly help...

Comment: Are you sure that the compose file matches the one on your machine? The environment section looks messed up. Please check if there were some typos when posting it here. Otherwise I would assume, you see some errors when running compose.

Comment: @Andreas, i do not see errors, but when starting boot app starts it tells active profile is ${ACTIVE_PROFILE}, but it doesnot take value "docker_development_cloud".. I am new to this, can you please guide as to what is messed up here :)

Comment: I think you mixed the array and the dictionary notation for passing the variables. See here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/environment. So either use hyphens (`-`) with equal signs (`=`) or the dictionary notation without hyphens but using colons (`:`). An easy way to debug this is to override the command with `env` which prints all environment variables.

Comment: eureka-server:
  image: controlsplm/eureka-server
  environment:
  - HOST_IP=13.68.114.134
  - ACTIVE_PROFILE=docker-development-cloud
  ports:
  - "8761:8761"
  restart: always                                                                                           With above both variables are not picked up by application

Comment: Please extend your question instead of pasting multiline code in the comments here. Have a look at the link I posted above and try `docker-compose run eureka-server env` to see which variables are available when the container is starting.

Comment: Thank you Andreas. My lack of knowledge here..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, if you have Spring properties

```
my.spring.property.one=green
my.spring.property.two=blue
```

You can include them as follows in the docker-compose.yml:

```
environment:
- my_spring_property_one=green
- my_spring_property_two=blue
```

worked for my with

- Spring Boot v1.5.10.RELEASE
- Spring v4.3.14.RELEASE
- docker version '3.6'

Comment: Thank you @yehouda-bouskila for suggesting; I partly accepted your changes, though: I am not sure the "." actually work as a separator. They did not with the indicated versions of spring etc.. If by now, they do, pls. post as separate answer incl. versions.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems:

1. the format of the `ACTIVE_PROFILE` is wrong, it would be `ACTIVE_PROFILE: docker-development-cloud` as mentioned by @andreas-jägle in the comments
2. The entrypoint uses json array notation, which means the command is exec'ed directly without a shell. The shell (usually `bash`) is what replaced the variables with their values, so you need to run in a shell to use those variables. You can either use the string form of `ENTRYPOINT`, or use:

   `ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "-c" ,"java - Dspring.profiles.active=$ACTIVE_PROFILE ..."]`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by adding below lines to my docker-compose.yml file:

```
eureka-server:
  image: controlsplm/eureka-server:latest
  environment:
     HOST_IP: X.X.X.X
     SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: docker-development-cloud
  ports:
   - "8761:8761"
  restart: always
```

and below lines in dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD eureka-server-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8761
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-Denvironment=$HOST_IP","-jar","/app.jar"]
```